# Matlab - Text file names from Cell array

Tags: matlab, cells

I've made a cell array that goes through the names of 50 text files I need to analyze. However, when referencing a particular character element as the title for **textread**, I get an error.

---

Example:

```
NameCell = {'file1.txt' 'file2.txt'};

vec = textread(NameCell{1},'%n','headerlines',23);
```

---

If I input the actual file name ('file1.txt') into the textread function, I get the vector I want, but it can't reference from the cell. Is there a way around this?

Thank you!

Comment: What does the error say? I didn't get any with your code.

Comment: ??? Undefined function or method 'exist' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> textread>noargname at 192
   arg = f(arg);

Error in ==> textread at 159
if (noargname(@exist,varargin{1}) ~= 2 ||
noargname(@exist,fullfile(cd,varargin{1})) ~= 2) ...

Error in ==> sample at 13
a = textread(b,'%n','headerlines',23);

where b = NameCell(some number);

Comment: So `b` is a cell, not a string. `b(1)` is not equivalent to `b{1}`. Try the latter instead.

Comment: I believe b is a string, when I run the line in the command window, the result is a string that is the name of the file.

Comment: Oh goodness you're right! I can't believe I was doing that wrong ({} vs ()). Thank you so much!